# Summing Mysql values on C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a mysql table with some user data, it has some products that holds the quantity, I wanted to sum each product quantity to get the product total quantity, I can't do Select 'my product name here' because I need to get all the products automatically, they can change at any moment so i'm creating a temporary table and deleting the clients info columns to get only the products from it.
The mysql command i'm using to get only the products from my table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TemporaryTable 
    SELECT RoteiroDia.* 
    FROM Clientes 
        INNER JOIN RoteiroDia ON Clientes.id=RoteiroDia.idCliente 
        INNER JOIN NomeRotas ON Clientes.idRota=NomeRotas.id 
        INNER JOIN Vendedores ON RoteiroDia.idVendedor=Vendedores.id 
        INNER JOIN Veiculos ON RoteiroDia.idPlaca=Veiculos.id 
    WHERE NRotas = 'placeHere' 
    AND Vendedores.Nome = 'nameHere' 
    AND Veiculos.Placa = 'nameHere' 
    AND RoteiroDia.Data = 'dateHere'; 

    ALTER TABLE TemporaryTable 
        DROP COLUMN FormaPagamento, 
        DROP COLUMN Obs, 
        DROP COLUMN id, 
        DROP COLUMN Data, 
        DROP COLUMN idRota, 
        DROP COLUMN idCliente, 
        DROP COLUMN pos, 
        DROP COLUMN idVendedor, 
        DROP COLUMN idPlaca, 
        DROP COLUMN Debito, 
        DROP COLUMN Acerto, 
        DROP COLUMN Diferença, 
        DROP COLUMN DinheiroRecebido, 
        DROP COLUMN AVista, 
        DROP COLUMN Despesas, 
        DROP COLUMN NovaVendas, 
        DROP COLUMN Entradas; 

    SELECT * FROM TemporaryTable;
```

What the mysql code gives me:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPvVd.png)

To sum them all into each "Product", I'm using this c# code here:
**I'm using the rdr2.fieldcount to get the product quantity (9 currently), then i'm looping through it and assigning the rdr.getint(0) to the produtoQuantidadeList[i]**

```
produtoQuantidadeList = new List<int>(new int[rdr2.FieldCount]);
int i = 0;
while (rdr2.Read())
{
    produtoQuantidadeList[i] += rdr2.GetInt32(0);
    if (i < rdr2.FieldCount - 1)
        i++;
    else
        i = 0;
}
```

I'm then using this here to debug the quantity:

```
for(int i = 0; i < produtoQuantidadeList.Count; i++)
    Console.WriteLine($"***** {produtoQuantidadeList[i]}");
```

But my c# code isnt summing them all correctly, apparently it cant get all the values from the table

What my table SUM() with the third product does:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVHHO.png)

Summing with my code:
[The third product (number 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evBjO.png)

Comment: If you can read it, there is just the possibilty you can debug it

Comment: I think you need to check "over partition by". You can use it to add a new column to the result set. It's easy and concise.

Comment: Hello T.kowshik Yedida, do you have any tips on how I can do that or any links? I've searched here and got tons of results, I have no idea of which one I should follow

Comment: @Technoo refer to the mysql documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html

Comment: @T.kowshikYedida I found no way of using this, because I need to get the products dynamically...

Comment: You are getting it dynamically but there is a select statement in the end. It is the final dataset you are going to use in c# as well if I am not wrong.

Comment: Oh, true, you know any way to sum all the columns separated without using concat? I can't do sum(*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem should be fixed like below:

```
produtoQuantidadeList = new int[rdr2.FieldCount];
while (rdr2.Read())
{
    // Loop all fields for each record
    for(int i=0; i < rdr2.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        // Sum the value of each field
        produtoQuantidadeList[i] += rdr2.GetInt32(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit over complicated.. Did you know you can remove columns from a result set by simply *not mentioning* them?.. If your Person table has Name and Age columns and you want a list of all the Names, you don't need to create a temp table from Person then drop the Age column.. you just don't select it:

```
SELECT Name FROM Person --no age column mentioned
```

Now to sum all of column 9 grouped by column 0:

```
SELECT Columns,You,Want,From,Roteiro, 
  SUM(column9NameHere) OVER(PARTITION BY galões) total_by_galoes
FROM
  ...
```

Of course, your screenshot only goes up to column 8 so I have no idea what your column 9 is called. Substitute the name in

Comment: Hey caius, the problem is that I need to select the products (galões, garrafões, vinho.. etc) dynamically, because it can change at any time.

Comment: Then your products should be in rows, not columns